# Session management when using @InboundChannelAdapter vs multiple SftpOutboundGateway to achieve same behaviour

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I have two services doing similar operations as listed below

Service A

Service A uses @InboundChannelAdapter and does following task

> 1. polls files every 1 minute from remote directory into local directory
> 2. deletes files from remote directory
> 3. process files from local directory
> 4. delete file from local directory

Service B

In Service B we are achieving similar but by using OutBoundGateway.

> 1. Using a external http call to invoke file downloading and processing
>    process every 1 minute
> 2. downloading the files from remote directory using OutBoundGateway
>    sftpchannel1
> 3. process the files from local download directory
> 4. delete files from remote directory using OutBoundGateway
>    sftpchannel2
> 5. delete files from local directory

My current concern is if we keep number of polls and file load same for both service A and B, then which service manages the ftpSession better.